# How to add value inside a loop

Tags: codeigniter-3

i have this code that suppose to sum up the count from a specific
function but all i do get is different

the printed value suppose to be 8 but am get 4 4 4 4 instead
 i have Tried any possible way to get it work but its difficult for me, every suggestion,ideal, recommendation is highly needed.
, please what must i do? or what am not doing
 here is the Code

```
public function upgrade_admin_to_prime(){
            //get the admins
            $admin_users    =$this->get_admin_user();
            foreach($admin_users as $row){
                $admin_username     =$row['username'];
                //check if my downline that is my ingress downline is upto 2
                $downline_count =$this->count_if_downline_is_complete($admin_username);
                if($downline_count == 2){
                    //get my downline user
                    $downline_users =$this->list_my_downline($admin_username);
                    foreach($downline_users as $row){
                        $downline_username  =$row['downline_username'];
                        //check if user downline count is 4 
                        //$downline_count2  ='';
                        $downline_count2    =$this->count_if_downline_is_complete($downline_username);
                        $downline_count2    =$downline_count2+$downline_count2;
                        if($downline_count2 == 4){
                $downline_users3    == // array of 4 users 'favor','kane','samson','fish'
                            foreach($downline_users3 as $row){
                                $downline_username3     =$row['downline_username'];
                                $downline_count3    =2;
                                echo $downline_count3    =$downline_count3+$downline_count3;
                                if($downline_count3 == 8){
                                    echo "Yess oo";
                                }else{
                                    echo "nope";
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            echo '2nd Generation Downline user count is not complete yet'.br();
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    echo 'your count is not complete yet'.br();
                }
            }
        }
```

i want this code here to Output 8 for me but its giving me 4 4 4 4

```
$downline_count3   =2;
                                echo $downline_count3    =$downline_count3+$downline_count3;
                                if($downline_count3 == 8){
                                    echo "Yes oo";
                                }else{
                                    echo "nope";
                                }
```

Comment: Which method and what part is related to the problem

Comment: You could perhaps simplify the code shown so that it's easier to know what you're asking.

Comment: ok let me edit it

Comment: @Zionnite by simplify I think @Mehdi means to make it into a verifiable and simple example, without having the other fuctions and  the same database structure it is very hard to decifer what is going on here. Perhaps provide us of an array of inputs so instead of `$this->count_if_downline_is_complete($admin_username);` the actual value of this function as an example.

Comment: i have edited it, is like this $downline_count3  =2

Comment: 2 + 2 = 4. How are you expecting that to be 8?